# UIscrollView DidScroll - only when touches

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I want to detect when user is scrolling a UIScrollView.
scrollViewDidScroll is called when that happens, but it's called also in another time -
when the user scrolls the view out of bounds, and then releases, the view jump back to it's place - and the method is called even though the user doesn't touch the screen at all (the view is scrolled by itself).

how can I detect scrolling and user touch together?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UIScrollView has a property `dragging` that indicates whether the scrolling was done by the user. So to see whether the user scrolls the scrollview or the scrolling is caused by something other (like an animation) you can do the following:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
   if (scrollView.dragging) {
      // scrolling is caused by user
   }
}
```

Comment: I used this in a UICollectionView to check if the scrolling was being done by the user or programatically.

Comment: Does the `dragging` property get set correctly when the user lets go of the screen and the scroll view is still scrolling due to momentum?

Comment: @LironYahdav If you're concerned you can always access the inner mechanism of the scrollview to get more specific. `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches` - the exact number of fingers currently&actively touching/sliding on the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

For **Swift 5**

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView.isDragging {
            print("Scroll View is scrolled by the user!")
        }
    }
```

Also make sure to assign the scroll views delegate to itself in the `videoDidLoad()`